# MS Access export report from another database

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba, export

I am basically trying to do the following (export as report as PDF):

```
DoCmd.OpenReport report_name, acViewPreview
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, report_name, acFormatPDF, dest, False
DoCmd.Close acReport, report_name
```

However I am trying to get it to reference a report object in a completely separate database. How do I modify report_name to get this to work? I've tried "[dbpath].[report_name]" to no avail. The report name has spaces in the name, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Access application session, open the other database, and use that session as the host application for your `Application.DoCmd` methods.

```vb
Dim objAccess As Access.Application
Set objAccess = New Access.Application

objAccess.Visible = True ' <- useful during development
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\wherever\YourDatabase.accdb"
With objAccess.DoCmd
    .OpenReport report_name, acViewPreview
    .OutputTo acOutputReport, report_name, acFormatPDF, dest, False
    .Close acReport, report_name
End With
objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
objAccess.Quit
Set objAccess = Nothing
```

Comment: Is there any reason why doing "new access.application" might result in reference errors? I sometimes hear that late binding is better than early binding for this reason.

Comment: Not a problem for `Access.Application`.  You're running VBA code in Access, and by default your project has a reference for the Access object library, and it's the proper version.  Late binding is useful in other cases where you can't be certain the expected version for the reference is available; or even whether any version of that reference is available.